# What is the best way of creating "half-offline" app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, offline

"Half-offline" app in my definition is an app with pre-populated data and the ability to update data.

For example:

- Recipe app
- Collection of quotes
- Short tales

When a user installs the app, it comes with a number of recipes/quotes/tales inside. Then after some time, a user can update the collection manually. Updates can be requested from Firebase or own servers.

So what is the most correct way to pre-populate a SQL/NoSQL database or file assets and what software I should use to pre-populate a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I prefer to start using `Firebase Firestore`, they already solved the online/offline structures, and you can do the steps by following [this article](https://atul-sharma-94062.medium.com/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27)

If you want to handle it by yourself, you can build and create your own SQLite, you can do that by following [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9376629-sqlite-in-flutter) too, in this stage you can update the data every week, month by calling a single API request from your side.